# SVN unused repository detection

Tags: svn

We have a lot of `SVN` repos in our setup. Most of them are not used by anyone. Is there a way to identify repos which did not have any activity over a period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a fast way to achieve your expected result, but with this command:

```
svn ls -Rv your_svn_host/your_project
```

you can extract a list of all files with revision and last date. Then you can redirect the generated list to a file and make a simple app to get the informations you want.